# python screenshot file moved or renamed

Tags: python, image, screenshot, python-imaging-library

I wrote a code on python which suppost to take a screenshot and show it.
shis is the code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab,Image
import PIL

def screenshot():
    num=1
    takescsh = ImageGrab.grab()
    takescsh.save(str(num)+'.png')
    takescsh.show()
    num=num+1

x=raw_input()
while x!='stop':
    screenshot()
    x=raw_input()
```

it opens the windows picture viewer but in the picture viewer it says "it looks like the file was moved or renamed"
any idea why it is like that?

Comment: I just tried the code you've posted and it did work in MacOSx!!

Comment: i've tried it on windows in more than one computer and it does not work

Comment: Its working in Mac :)

Answer (score 0):

In the `screenshot` function, `num` is always equal to `1`. So, each and every time you call `screenshot`, the file is rewritten on the disk. Try something like:

```
def screenshot(num):
    takescsh = ImageGrab.grab()
    takescsh.save(str(num) + '.png')
    takescsh.show()


count = 1
while 'Capturing':
    screenshot(count)
    count += 1
    if raw_input() == 'stop':
        break
```

Comment: Is it OK for you? If yes, could you accept the answer please?